# Detect if jQuery MMenu is open/active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I'm using [jQuery MMenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) and need to use the API to detect whether or not the menu is open.

I've looked over their [Events](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/events.php) page, but I cannot figure out how to get it's status.

Will someone please give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: add an attribute when you open the menu, remove it when it's closed, and check for that attribute to know if its open or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs stated, you can use:

1) `opening` event to trigger your function when the menu is opening.

```
$("#nav").mmenu().trigger("open.mm").on("opening.mm", function() {
    alert( "The menu is opening" );
});
```

2) `opened` event to trigger your function when the menu is finished opening

```
$("#nav").mmenu().trigger("open.mm").on("opened.mm", function() {
    alert( "The menu has just been opened." );
});
```

---

Edit: When your `menu` is active, it will has class `mm-opened` in `<nav id="left">`, you can check:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    if($('#left').hasClass('mm-opened')) {
        $("#nav").trigger("close.mm")
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I'm wanting check it's status to use a link to toggle (open/close) the menu. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I was wondering how to force mmenue to open when the user navigates to the page without clicking a button or a burger menu. I can open another question if you are interested. Thanks.