# open and closing mmenu on same button

Tags: javascript, mmenu

I´m using mmenu and I use clickopen function to get the menu open. I want also close the mmenu with the same button.. Here is the code that handles the event to open the menu:

```
// Handles clickOpen event.
        if (mmenu.options.clickOpen) {
          if (mmenu.options.clickOpen.open && mmenu.options.clickOpen.selector) {
            $(mmenu.options.clickOpen.selector).bind('click', {name: mmenu.name}, function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              $('#' + e.data.name).trigger('open.mm');
            });
          }
        }
      }
```

Is it possible to edit the code above or can this be done by some javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how? Because I don´t

Comment: "Do you know how?" yes. I am not trolling you, just pointing out the natural answers to your questions. Please take a moment to read the guide on posting questions. In the meantime, this link will help you solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003846/detect-if-jquery-mmenu-is-open-active

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of achieving this:

```
$('#menu').mmenu();

$('#menubutton').on('click', function () {
    var api = $('#menu').data('mmenu');

    if (document.documentElement.className.indexOf("mm-opened") >= 0) {
        api.close();
    }
    else {
        api.open();
    }
});
```

This way the same button `#menubutton` can be used for both opening and closing the mmenu.